# Adding Popup to the phaser game

Tags: javascript, jquery, phaser-framework

I want to add popup to the game. I am using phaser and found modal.js for adding popup in phaser it seems to be useful but when i am trying to add this i am getting an error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'modal1' of undefined". I think i am getting this error just because of my coding structure. Here is my code

```
var reg={};
createModals: function(){
    reg.modal.createModal({
        type: "modal1",
        includeBackground: true,
        modalCloseOnInput: true,
        itemsArr: [{
            type: "graphics",
            graphicColor: "0xffffff",
            graphicWidth: 300,
            graphicHeight: 300,
            graphicRadius: 40
        }, {
            type: "text",
            content: "The white behind me\nis a [Phaser.Graphic]",
            fontFamily: "Luckiest Guy",
            fontSize: 22,
            color: "0x1e1e1e",
            offsetY: -50
        }, ]
    });

    },

    showModal1: function(){
    reg.modal.showModal("modal1");
    }
```

can any help with this...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an complete example.

```js
var reg = {};

function createModals() {
  reg.modal.createModal({
            type:"modal1",
            includeBackground: true,
            modalCloseOnInput: true,
            itemsArr: [
                {
            type: "graphics",
            graphicColor: "0xffffff",
            graphicWidth: 300,
            graphicHeight: 300,
            graphicRadius: 40
        }, {
            type: "text",
            content: "The white behind me\nis a [Phaser.Graphic]",
            fontFamily: "Luckiest Guy",
            fontSize: 22,
            color: "0x1e1e1e",
            offsetY: -50
        }
            ]
        }); 
}

function showModal1(){
  reg.modal.showModal("modal1");
}

var GameState = function(game) {
};

GameState.prototype.create = function() {
  reg.modal = new gameModal(game);
  createModals();
  var m1 = this.game.add.button(30, 50, "m1", showModal1);
};

var game = new Phaser.Game(750, 380, Phaser.CANVAS, 'game');
game.state.add('game', GameState, true);
```

```html
<script src="http://netgfx.com/trunk/games/phaser_modals/phaser.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://netgfx.com/trunk/games/phaser_modals/modal.js"></script>
<div style="font-family:'Luckiest Guy',cursive;visibility:hidden;opacity:0;position:fixed;">&nbsp;</div>
```

Comment: i am getting an error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'modals' of undefined
    at new gameModal (modal.js:8)
    at patternsRatio.game1.create (game1.js:97)
    at Phaser.StateManager.loadComplete (phaser.js:30083)
    at Phaser.Loader.finishedLoading (phaser.js:74233)
    at Phaser.Loader.processLoadQueue (phaser.js:74190)
    at Phaser.Loader.asyncComplete (phaser.js:74263)
    at Phaser.Loader.fileComplete (phaser.js:75120)
    at HTMLImageElement.file.data.onload (phaser.js:74522)"

Answer (score 3):

I'm the creator of this lib, it seems that you are not passing the correct game object on the constructor.

```
reg.modal = new gameModal(game);
```

if your game object is not called `game` you need to pass the correct game object.

Usually this comes from this line

```
var game = new Phaser.Game(1024, 768, Phaser.AUTO, 'game', null, true);
```

So that `game` is a global variable

@Jatin patil is correct in his answer.